# Комментарии (велосипед)

Tags: django

Я новичок и пишу свою систему комментариев к постам. Вот такой код:
models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
   user=models.ForeignKey(CustomUser)
   post=models.ForeignKey(Post)
   text=models.TextField(verbose_name=u'Текст комментария')
   time=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Meta:
    ordering=['-time']

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.user.username+" "+self.post.header
```

forms.py

```
class ComForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model=Comment
    fields=('text',)

def save(self, user, post):
    obj=super(ComForm, self).save(commit=False)
    obj.user=user
    obj.post=str(post)
    return obj.save()
```

views.py

```
def Posts(request, id):
if request.method=='GET':
    post=Post.objects.get(id=id)
    comments=Comment.objects.filter(post=str(id)).all()
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        addform=ComForm(request.POST or None, instance=request.user)
    return render_to_response("posts.html", locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request, processors=[default]))
if request.method=='POST':
    comment=ComForm(request.POST)
    if comment.is_valid():
        comment.save(request.user, id)
return HttpResponseRedirect("/posts/"+id)
```

Выдает ошибку "Cannot assign "'4'": "Comment.post" must be a "Post" instance." при сохранении комментария. Как заставить работать это существо?

Comment: Велосипедостроение, конечно, полезно для развития. Цель - развитие или все-таки система комментариев? Если второе, у Django есть встроенный [comments framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/)

Comment: Не понимаю, зачем в `Comment.save` сперва вызывать `super` без коммита, потом изменять данные, а потом вновь сохранять? Почему бы сразу не присвоить данные и вызвать `save` родителя?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну так, все ж из ошибки понятно: `Comment.post` должен быть инстансом модели `Post`. А вы в `ComForm.save` присваиваете строку: `obj.post=str(post)`. Вместо этого нужно передать инстанс, как-то так: `obj.post = Comment.objects.get(post=post)`

Comment: Cпасибо за советы. Цель - действительно развитие

Comment: Попробовал изменить код согласно Вашим советам, появилась другая ошибка "Comment matching query does not exist."

Comment: Нашел решение проблемы. Во views.py post=Post.objects.get(id=id), а в forms.py obj.post=post

Comment: Да, косяк. Я исправил в ответе. Получать нужно не по `id`, разумеется, а по `post`